# Is it possible to transform a metric tensor that has both 1's and −1's on the diagonal to a form in which only 1's are present?

Tags: metric-spaces, tensors

For example, can one change the coordinate system so that the metric tensor of signature $g_{\mu\nu} = diag(1,1,-1)$ is brought into the form $g_{\mu\nu} = diag(1,1,1)$?
I guess not, because otherwise the Minkowsky metric could be reshaped to be completely positive, but I cannot find a good way to prove it.

Comment: Do you know Sylvester's law of inertia? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia

Comment: Thanks, that's it!